# Probability of getting number greater than 4 given there is at least one tail .(Conditional Probability)

Tags: probability

Consider the experiment of tossing a coin. If the coin shows head, toss it
again but if it shows tail, then throw a die. Find the
conditional probability of the event that ‘the die shows
a number greater than 4’ given that ‘there is at least
one tail’.

Now,I know how to do this question using multiplication theorems of probability and the answer is 2/9 but the book solves this question before starting the topic of multiplication theorems.

**So my question is simple?Can it be solved without using multiplication theorems and using the basic probability knowledge,preferably after knowing addition theorem and conditional probability but before multiplication theorem?Any hints?**

Link:Page 7 http://ncertbooks.prashanthellina.com/class_12.Mathematics.MathematicsPartII/Probability%2018.11.06.pdf

Comment: Have you reproduced the exact question ?

Comment: @true blue anil Yes.The 1st paragraph.After that my question.

Comment: You only do one round of this?  So, given that there is "at least one tail" means "the single toss of the coin comes up tails"?  But then the answer is $\frac 26$.

Comment: @lulu Yes,only one round,I have added the link also.

Comment: Oh, I get it.  I'll post something below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is (somewhat) ambiguous.  As I (now) read it the coin portion of the game has three possible outcomes $$\{HH,HT,T\}$$  These are not equally likely. Indeed the first two have probability $\frac 14$ each, and the last has probability $\frac 12$.  Only in the latter event do you actually roll the die (thus I think the problem ought to read "given that you the coin ends up $T$ what is the probability that you throw the die and see a value greater than $4$." )  We note that the probability of the coin portion ending in $T$ is $\frac 34$

Anyway, now you can do a tree.  The outcomes that involve a $T$ are $\{T,_\}$ with probability $\frac 14$ and $\{T,i\}$ for $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and each of these has probability $\frac 1{12}$.  We note that exactly two of these events pass the "greater than $4$" test and that these events have a combined probability of $\frac 2{12}$. Thus our answer is $$\frac {\frac 2{12}}{\frac 34}=\frac 2{12}\times \frac 43 =\frac 8{36}=\frac 29$$

Comment: So how did you get 1/4 without multiplying 1/2 with itself,I mean how did you get 1/4 using only the sample space?(Because I want to know how to get probability in this question without using multiplication theorem)

Comment: I did multiply them.  That's exactly how it is done in your book.  They draw the tree and carefully write out the probability along each branch (by multiplying).  My argument isn't all that different, I think it's just a little cleaner.

Comment: But ,but they taught the topic **after** doing this question,anyway your answer is helpful,that must be incorrect placement in the book.Thanks:)

Comment: Well, if you really want to avoid the multiplication...enumerate the coin part as $4$ equi-probable states  $\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$  Here the last two states are summed up as what I called just $T$ before.  Now it's clear that $HT$ has probability $\frac 14$.

Comment: And for the tails and dice I would consider it(sample space) for **both** Heads and tails and 6 numbers of the dice to get 12 outcomes or something else?

Comment: If you really want all your events to be equi-probable then I think it's best to roll the die regardless of the outcome of the coin toss (you can just ignore the ones that you weren't meant to roll).  Thus every event looks like two coin tosses and a die roll, and each event has probability $\frac {1}{24}$.

Comment: Okay,this got more complicated,I thank you for your patience and this answer but I don't want events to be equi-probable. I just wanted to know whether the book uses something other than Multiplication theorem and if yes,how.(But I think I need not go into that):p

Comment: If it helps:  I think the book's ordering of topics is eccentric.  In the tree they draw they simply write $\frac 14$ with no explanation.  My guess is that they used the product rule...but they might have done it by mentally listing out all the events and then not writing out the ones they didn't care about.  It really isn't clear.  My advice:  stick to the product rule.

Comment: Okay,thanks for the advice.